# scp from GCP VM to my local machine gets permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to download files from my GCP VM using scp into my local computer. However, I get permission denied:

```
gcloud beta compute scp --project "project-id" --zone "europe-west4-a" instance-2:/home/username/my_bucket_2/file.txt ./
```

error:

```
scp: /home/username/my_bucket_2/file.txt: Permission denied
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

Comment: What are the permission of the file on the instance? Did you try to specify the connection user `.......  username@instance-2:/home/username/my_bucket_2/file.txt ./`? If it works I will post it as answer.

Comment: specify username before "@" worked. Why did the people at GCP not know that....

Comment: It's not really GCP, it's linux/ssh behavior. I learnt that with experience and years. If your GCP contact is a junior, it's possible that is not aware of that. Even engineers at Google create bugs! No one is perfect!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a gcloud compute ssh or scp, the user used by default, for the connection, is the current user connected on the terminal.

If the name on the compute instance VM isn't the same, you need to specify with which user account you want to log into the VM to have access to files. Here the files are in the user directory, and by default, another user can't access them.

So, for that, you can specify the user for the SSH/SCP connexion instead of letting gcloud SDK pick the default one

```
gcloud beta compute scp --project "project-id" --zone "europe-west4-a" \
  username@instance-2:/home/username/my_bucket_2/file.txt ./
```